# Options +Indexes of .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a website running on a server. It's just an `index.html` with a hello world text. Also, I have a folder named `/vpn` which contains various txt files and an `index.html` file.

If I try to access the URL `domain/vpn`, it shows me the content of `index.html`.

I just need to show the files inside the folder vpn when the user tries to access `domain/vpn`.

I created an `.htaccess` file with the next content in the root:

```
RewriteEngine on
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/vpn/'">
   DirectoryIndex disabled
   Options +Indexes
</If>
```

When I try to access to vpn, it shows me a 404 error, the requested URL was not found on this server.

`.htaccess` is applying the `DirectoryIndex` rule (If a delete it, it shows me `index.html` content again), but not the `Options +Indexes` one.

I tried the same example in localhost (with XAMPP) and it's working fine.

What can be the problem?

PD: This is the content of `apache2.conf` file:

[image: apache2.conf]

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to acces to vpn, it shows me a 404 error, the requested URL was not found on this server.

If you are getting a "404 Not Found" then it would imply that **mod_autoindex** is not actually *installed* on your server (consequently `Options +Indexes` has no effect - although it would seem from your server config that `Indexes` is perhaps already enabled).

mod_autoindex is the module responsible for generating the directory listings.

> I created an `.htaccess` file with the next content in the root:

Personally, I would create an additional `.htaccess` file in the `/vpn` directory instead:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
Options +Indexes
```

And disable `Indexes` (and set `DirectoryIndex`) in the root `.htaccess` file.

NB: `RewriteEngine` has no place here, unless you are overriding a parent config.

> If I try to access the url "domain/vpn"

Note that you should be requesting `domain/vpn/` (with a trailing slash). If you omit the trailing slash then mod_dir issues a 301 redirect to append it.